# Hide keyboard when navigating from a fragment to another

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

I have a Fragment that contains an Edit Text. When the Edit Text is pressed, the keyboard is being shown. When pressed the Save button in the upper corner, the application returns to the previous fragment, but the keyboard persists.

I would like the keyboard to be hidden when navigating to the previous fragment.

Please, note that I tried this solution:
[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard).

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

I tried to use this in both fragments, in the onCreate method.

I also tried to hide the soft keyboard in the layout:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

None of these worked, unfortunately.

I would have posted some pictures, but I do not have enough reputation yet. 
I would appreciate any constructive help and opinion and do not forget that "A wise man can learn more from a foolish question than a fool can learn from a wise answer." :)

Regards, 
Alexandra

Comment: It is an ordinary Edit Text. Just as in the solution.

Comment: Try using getView() (method from Fragment)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Put the code that hides the keyboard in your "save button" click listener, and use this method to hide the keyboard:

```
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // check if no view has focus:
         View currentFocusedView = activity.getCurrentFocus();
         if (currentFocusedView != null) {
             inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocusedView.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Put that code in a public class and then you can call it with one line from whatever fragment needs it. Good stuff - been looking for this for ages

Answer (score 17):

### Kotlin

For Kotlin, you can use this as a top level function, just add the code to a separate class such as `Utils.kt`.

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val inputMethodManager =
        activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

    // Check if no view has focus
    val currentFocusedView = activity.currentFocus
    currentFocusedView?.let {
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            currentFocusedView.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
    }
}
```

To access it from Fragment, call it like:

```
hideKeyboard(activity as YourActivity)
```

Thanks to Silvia H for Java code.

Comment: could be `activity.currentFocus?.let { currentFocusedView -> `

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to hide keyboard in fragment or Activity

Soluton : 1

```
//hide keyboard
public static void hideKeyboard(Context ctx) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // check if no view has focus:
    View v = ((Activity) ctx).getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null)
        return;

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Solution : 2

```
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // check if no view has focus:
         View currentFocusedView = activity.getCurrentFocus();
         if (currentFocusedView != null) {
             inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocusedView.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the keyboard by putting this code in your onPause in the fragment you're leaving.

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
    requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using above answers, i tried to implement it for ones who uses navigation component.

Try below code and it will work fine

```
private fun setupNavigatingListener() {
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { navController: NavController, navDestination: NavDestination, bundle: Bundle? ->
        currentFocus?.let { Utils.hideKeyboard(it) }
    }
}
```

Utils class

```
    fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputManager =
            view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin its very easy:

simple create an extension function can call it from anywhere you get context

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    view?.let { activity?.hideKeyboard(it) }
}

fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```