# How to close/hide custom keyboard Android

Tags: android, hide, android-softkeyboard, android-context, custom-keyboard

I've try to close my custom keyboard after click item in gridview.I'm trying to do it in BaseAdapter class. context is come from InputMethodService.

So far I've tried below:

```
FrameLayout scroll = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(scroll.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

--

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(0,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

--

```
 scroll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have your own custom keyboard and you have extended `InputMethodService`, then you can just call

```
requestHideSelf(0)
```

from within your service to force close the keyboard or

```
requestHideSelf(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

to close the keyboard only if the user didn't explicitly request it to be shown.

**Documentation**

- [`InputMethodService`#`void requestHideSelf (int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#requestHideSelf(int))

Answer (score 2):

I'm just copying and pasting from my app here, it works fine for us:

```
   public static void hideKeyboard(View v) {
      try {
         v.clearFocus();
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // we all saw shit happening on this code before
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this method in a public class, and call it wherever needed.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context ctx) {
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx
.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

// check if no view has focus:
 View v = ((Activity) ctx).getCurrentFocus();
 if (v == null)
    return;

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911627/1385488)

Comment: i get cannot get cast to Android.app.Activity error , my context class extends InputMethodService :( i cant use activity (if there is a way i dont know )

Comment: If you're in a keyboard, you hide yourself via requestHideSelf.  But your keyboard probably doesn't have a gridView, so i think you're a bit confused.